# Dynamic Chart in PHP using Chart js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chart.js

I am not being able to show the values from my PHP file into my HTML file using Chart js. I am trying to import it through AJAX request. I tried it through printing the database value as JSON in the PHP file. The encoding worked well but I can't show them in graph for some reason. Please suggest any other way if possible to do the task mentioned in the code

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Chart.js demo</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/0.2.0/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/LineGraph.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Chart.js Sample</h1>
    <div  id= "graphDiv" style="width:100%; height:auto;">
    
    </div>
    <script>
        
        showGraph();
        
        function showGraph(){
            $.post("agSensorInterfaceUpdate.php", function (data){
                
                console.log(data);
                var ctx = $("#graphCanvas");
                var acc_data = [];
                var gyr_data = [];
                var serial = [];
                    
                for(var i in data) {
                    acc_data.push(data[i].accelerometer);
                    gyr_data.push(data[i].gyroscope);
                    serial.push(data[i].serial_no);
                }
                    
                var chartdata = {
                    labels: serial_no,
                    datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Accelerometer Data',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200,200,0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200,200,0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200,200,200,1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200,200,200,1)',
                        data: acc_data
                    }
                    ]
                };
                    
                    
                    
                var lineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type:'line',
                    data: chartdata
                });
                
                
            });
        }
            
        
        
    </script>
    
</body>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
      header('Content-Type: application/json');
         
        
      $username = "root";
      $password = "";
      $database = "arthor_bb";
      $serial=1;
      $sensor_value = array();
      
      $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);
      
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `sensor_data`";
      
      $result = $mysqli->query($query);
      foreach ($result as $row){
            $sensor_value[] = $row;
            
      }
      
      $result -> close();
      
      
      print json_encode($sensor_value);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

your "graphDiv" html element needs to be a canvas. not a div.

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="100%" height="50%"></canvas>
```

You also have the wrong id on your ctx variable.

```
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'); // canvas
```

Comment: I changed every error that you pointed out. Still didn't work

Comment: Are you really using Chartjs 0.2.0? Why would you ever do that?

Comment: What version? Also should `labels: serial_no` be `labels: serial`?